# I get an error: Property "CListView.afterAjaxUpdate " is not defined. when using afterAjaxUpdate in clistview in yii

Tags: php, yii, clistview

I have made a simple list view to show a list of posts. I have attached a number of buttons in each post and have attached click function to each of those buttons. I am trying to bind the click events those buttons in the post with afterAjaxUpdate property of the clistview. But I get the error: Property "CListView.afterAjaxUpdate " is not defined.

My clistview setup is as follows:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$posts,
        'afterAjaxUpdate '=>'clickEvents',
        'itemView'=>'_post',
        'summaryText'=>'',
        'id'=>'posts-list',
    ));
```

I get that error when using both 1.14 and 1.15. I checked the class file for clistview and I can see the property listed. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: you have " " after "afterAjaxUpdate". and use `'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:clickEvents()'` to call js function.

Comment: ineersa is right, remove the space.